# How can i configure my router wifi to be on the same network

Tags: networking, router, ip, lan, subnet

Hello everyone at my job my boss ask me to configure four router to extend our networking for people (I work in center with a lot of people and activity) I manage to put every router working and everyone can have internet BUT like you can see in my beautiful drawing there is two network my FAI one : 192.168.1.114 / and my router 10.10.10.101 Both need to communicate between them I mean to have the same network and not a subnet from my router. Because now people who connect in the router can't see the cloud server with all of they're work because because this one is connect on my fai port and have 192.168.1.119 as an ip so people connected directly on my fai box can see it but the other connect on my router can't see it and it's very problematic !

I try a lot of thing but I heard there is a thing called Bridge mode but when I look closely it's seems to be only configure in wireless mode to a router at another but all mine are very far and connected directly to my fai by a cable so what are my solution ?

I'm totally new at this thing so I'm a bit lost !

I hope you could help me ! Have a nice day ! p-s : sorry for my bad english it's not my native language[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmjGP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "bridge" mode (or "access point" mode) is exactly what you're looking for. It is very commonly used for bridging Wi-Fi to Ethernet.

It *does not* require using a wireless uplink – if your routers say it does, then you're looking at the wrong option.

1. You might be looking in the wrong place. Bridging doesn't change anything about how Wi-Fi works, it changes how the *WAN port* works – so it won't be in the "Wireless" section, it's more likely to be under the "WAN" section or "Networking" section or something similar.
2. The setting might be named differently. Sometimes it's called "access point" mode, because wireless routers without routing are just access points.
3. And some wireless routers just don't have bridge mode setting at all – their WAN port is always in router mode.

   However, the 'LAN' ports are *always* bridged to Wi-Fi, so in that case you can just move the Ethernet connection from 'WAN' port to one of the 'LAN' ports. (And don't forget to disable DHCP and UPnP services in the routers.)

Comment: So, at first I try to found the wan section but there wasn't the option I need it ! I try to connect the LAN PORT and disable DHCP ( Didn't have UPnP) and its works for now thanks you !